# "Cannot replace" error on git forced push

Tags: git, git-push

Am trying to do a forced push (--force) of a branch to a repository. I get the below error. The error doesn't say non-fastforward or any other permission issues and instead just says cannot replace. When i try the push again it succeeds. Not sure only in few situation this fails. Has anyone come across this error "cannot replace"

```
remote: Processing changes: refs: 2, done            
    To ssh://user1@server.com:1234/drivers/driver1.git
     ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> rel-branch (cannot replace 2815)
    error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://user1@server.com:1234/drivers/driver.git'
```

Comment: This looks as there is some hook on the remote repository which rejects that push with the message "cannot replace 2815". Can you find out which hooks are installed in the remote repository?

Comment: Thanks, am sure and confirmed I don't have any hooks on the repos.

Comment: Are you using gerrit for the remote repository? That [seems](https://github.com/gracefullife/gerrit/blob/master/gerrit-server/src/main/java/com/google/gerrit/server/git/ReceiveCommits.java#L1663) to use the message "cannot replace" when the user is not allowed to push some changes.

Comment: Yes i use Gerrit on the remote repository but the push was done using a manual push command without involving Gerrit